# Upgrading pip before installing requirements on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using a library (`weasyprint`) that requires a newer version of pip than what is provided by the AWS Beanstalk platform. I have an `.ebextensions` file that upgrades pip like so:

```
commands:
  01_upgrade_pip:
    command: '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip'
    ignoreErrors: false
```

Thing is, every time the instance is rebuilt, the `weasyprint` install fails, but if I try to deploy again on the same instance, it successfully deploys. My guess is that pip isn't getting upgraded before `weasyprint` gets installed, and then the second time around pip is upgraded so it works. Is there a way to ensure pip gets upgraded as soon as the instance is created?

I'm using `Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.7`

Comment: I assume that your Beanstalk is creating ASG with some default AMIs. If that is the case you can create/modify userdata file in ASG and add the steps of upgrading pip there. Alternatively, you can check if there is an AMI with upgraded pip available, then you can use that instead. Check out details at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-view-change

Comment: i can't control what gets executed on the EC2 instances directly - I can only use `.ebextensions` to run commands. The issue I'm having is the commands don't seem to be running in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
commands:
  01_upgrade_pip:
    command: '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install weasyprint'
    ignoreErrors: false
```

or you could make a file like `pip_install.sh`, and do something like this:

```
commands:
      01_run_installer:
        command: 'bash /path/to/pip_install.sh'
        ignoreErrors: false
```

ElasticBeanstalk also supports docker, so you could run everything inside a docker container, so you'd have complete control over the installation.

I'm sure one of these methods should work, but it's been a while since I've used ElasticBeanstalk.

Answer (score -3):

You go onto your command prompt and you have to get your file location set for where you have your python file. After that you

```
upgrade pip
```

That's all you do and after that, you will be able to function everything.